# how to extract data from a database with node-red

Tags: mysql, node-red

i have a database `arduino` with one table `sensordata`

```
+-------------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| humidite    | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| temperature | float | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I inserted some data in my `sensordata` table

```
mysql> select *from sensordata ;
+----------+-------------+
| humidite | temperature |
+----------+-------------+
|     4.98 |          50 |
|     7.98 |          90 |
+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

now the node-red part

[image: myflow]
1. my query

[image: my query]
2. mysql the settings

[image: mysql settings]
the output 
[image: output]

I thought I would have something like in the node-red web page but it don't work

```
+------------------------+ 
 humidite  | temperature |
+----------+-------------+
|     4.98 |          50 |
|     7.98 |          90 |
+----------+-------------+
```

help me please !!!!

Comment: The flow you've shared has nothing at the start to trigger it. Have you added an Inject node at the start of your flow so you can actually run it?

Comment: no i didn't it is mandatory in your opinion ?

Comment: All flows need to be triggered by something